# UILocalNotification repeat interval not working

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to have the UILocalNotification repeat every second, and it is indeed repeating, but not every second for some reason, it seems to repeat every minute instead, I'm still new to UILocalNotifications so I might be doing something wrong. Here's a pic of the notifs: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGGg6.jpg

Here's the function I'm using to create the UILocalNotification

```
       func notificationCreater (date:NSDate, uuid:String) {

    let notification = UILocalNotification ()

    notification.alertBody = "Test Run 9"

    notification.fireDate = date
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond
    //notification.userInfo = ["UUID": uuid]
    //  notification.soundName = "alarmSound.m4a"
    //        notification.alertAction = "he"
    // notification.soundName = "alarmSound.m4a"
    // notification.alertTitle = "Test Title"

    println("schld")
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

Here's the rest of the View Controller

```
class AddTaskViewController: UIViewController,AVAudioPlayerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var taskTextField: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var dueDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
    var delegate = AddTaskViewControllerDelegate?()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Background")!)


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func cancelButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        delegate?.addTaskCanceled!("task canceled")
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()

    }

    @IBAction func addTaskButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

        let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)

        let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TaskModel", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
        let task = TaskModel(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

        task.task = taskTextField.text

        task.date = dueDatePicker.date
        task.uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
        //if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(kShouldCompleteNewTodoKey) == true {task.completed = true}
        task.completed = false

        appDelegate.saveContext()


        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let comp = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: task.date)


        let seconds = Double(comp.second)
        //        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        //        notification.alertBody = "testBody"
        //        notification.fireDate = dueDatePicker.date
        //        notification.alertTitle = "testTitle"
        println("seconds:\(seconds)")

        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TaskModel")
        var error:NSError? = nil

        var results:NSArray = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)!
        notificationCreater(dueDatePicker.date, uuid: task.uuid)

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

The notification is created when the add task button is clicked, but it doesn't repeat every second. What am I doing wrong?

**Also anyone know how to play the notification sound even when the phone is in "Do Not Disturb" or silent mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple's documentation [repeatInterval](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/repeatInterval)

> If you assign a calendar unit such as weekly (NSWeekCalendarUnit) or
>   yearly (NSYearCalendarUnit), the system reschedules the notification
>   for delivery at the specified interval. **Note that intervals of less
>   than one minute are not supported.** The default value is 0, which means
>   that the system fires the notification once and then discards it.

Answer (score 0):

App should be in background to trigger the notification. If you want to trigger the notification when the app is in foreground also  then  implement

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification){
```

}

Comment: The app was in the background, thats how it received those minutely notifications, (check the imgur) but it fails to repeat every second and is repeating every minute instead