# Repeat Interval is not working correctly for local notifications (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification

My repeat interval is going off about every 60 seconds no matter what I have it set to. Here is my code. Also whenever it repeats every 60 seconds, two notifications go off at once. To clarify what I am trying to do, I want my notification to go off once a week to remind the players of my sprite kit game to come back and play.

```
    let localNotification = UILocalNotification() // Creating an instance of the notification.
    localNotification.alertTitle = "Title"
    localNotification.alertBody = "Body"
    localNotification.alertAction = "Launch"
    localNotification.repeatInterval = .Hour
    localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName // Use the default notification tone/ specify a file in the application bundle
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1 // Badge number to set on the application Icon.
    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)        
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification) // Scheduling the notification.
```

Comment: this is not a duplicate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32256061/2303865

Comment: this still doesnt answer my question because my question is not a duplicate

Comment: Yeah it is still not working. repeating every 60 seconds

Comment: Read the link, "Note that intervals of less than one minute are not supported"... If you want to fire a date every second there are other ways to do it. Sort of a "hacky" way is to create an `NSTimer()` which calls its `selector` every `second` until you want to `invalidate` the timer

Comment: @ConnorB there is no `.Week` unit try `.WeekOfYear`. How would you expect us to believe you when you said it still not working. You posted a code that does not even compile

Comment: I meant to put .Weekday I have edited the questions again to fix that

Comment: What don't you understand? No matter if it is .Day or .Hour the notification is repeating every 60 seconds. This is not a duplicate and I need the question reopened. If not delete it.

Comment: @ConnorB If you don't use a valid unit then the default is 60seconds... have you used any valid unit yet?

Comment: I tried localNotification.repeatInterval = .Hour and it does not work... Is that not a valid unit?

Comment: It repeats every 60 seconds. Even if I have it set to .Hour

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Don't forget to remove/cancel all schedule notification

Comment: I believe that was the issue.  Do I have to remove them only once or how do I go about doing that

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/cancelAllLocalNotifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happened was that you tried to schedule a invalid repeatInterval unit. The minimum repeat interval unit it is .Minute. So What happened when you tried a valid unit it worked but you were still receiving the first schedule notification that was set by default to repeat every minute.

Just cancel all previous schedule notifications and schedule a new one.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/cancelAllLocalNotifications